# How to read arbitrary but continuous n lines from a huge file

Tags: java

I would like to read arbitrary number of lines. The files are normal ascii text files for the moment (they may be UTF8/multibyte character files later)

So what I want is for a method to read a file for specific lines only (for example from 101-200) and while doing so it should not block any thing (ie same file can be read by another thread for 201-210 and it should not wait for the first reading operation.

In the case there are no lines to read it should gracefully return what ever it could read. The output of the methods could be a List

The solution I thought up so far was to read the entire file first to find number of lines as well as the byte positions of each new line character. Then use the RandomAccessFile to read bytes and convert them to lines. I have to convert the bytes to Strings (but that can be done after the reading is done). I would avoid the end of file exception for reading beyond file by proper book keeping. The solution is bit inefficient as it does go through the file twice, but the file size can be really big and we want to keep very little in the memory.

If there is a library for such thing that would work, but a simpler native java solution would be great.

As always I appreciate your clarification questions and I will edit this question as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and just loop through hasNextLine() until you get to the count you want, and then grab as many lines as you wish... if it runs out, it'll fail gracefully. That way you're only reading the file once (unless Scanner reads it fully... I've never looked under the hood... but it doesn't sound like you care, so... there you go :)

Comment: getting the number of lines is easy, but I don't see how one can skip the first n lines with the scanner without iterating over all of them.

Comment: I didn't say you could, I think the scanner is willing to move its line index forward really fast though, so, you loop though looking for your desired line: while(myScanner.hasNextLine() && currentLine++ < desiredLine)...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimise memory consumption, I would use a memory mapped file.  This uses almost no heap.  The amount of the file kept in memory is handled by the OS so you don't need to tune the behaviour yourself.

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(fileName).getChannel();
final MappedByteBuffer map = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
```

If you have a file of 2 GB or more, you need multiple mappings.  In the simplest case you can scan the data and remember all the indexes.  The indexes them selves could take lots of space so you might only remember every Nth e.g. every tenth.

e.g. a 2 GB file with 40 byte lines could have 50 million lines requiring 400 MB of memory.

Another way around having a large index is to create another memory mapped file.

```
FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(fileName).getChannel();
final MappedByteBuffer map2 = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, fc.size()/10);
```

The problem being, you don't know how big the file needs to be before you start.  Fortunately if you make it larger than needed, it doesn't consume memory or disk space, so the simplest thing to do is make it very large and truncate it when you know the size it needs to be.

This could also be use to avoid re-indexing the file each time you load the file (only when it is changed)  If the file is only appended to, you could index from the end of the file each time.

Note: Using this approach can use a lot of virtual memory, for a 64-bit JVM this is no problem as your limit is likely to 256 TB.  For a 32-bit application, you limits is likely to be 1.5 - 3.5 GB depending on your OS.